# Failed to load image from MySQL to PHP page

Tags: php, android, image, base64, blob

I creating a system that contains android apps (for user) and web (for admin). In Android apps, there a camera function that allowed the user to snap the photo and store the photo to the MySQL database. I use method Encode Base64 to store the image to the database and Decode Base64 to display back the image from the database to the Android Apps. The image formate that store at the MySQL is BLOB. At Android Apps, everything runs well. Below is the current code for encode decode at android apps:

```
public static String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap image) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
    byte[] byteArray = os.toByteArray();
    String encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImageString ;
}

public static Bitmap base64ToBitmap(String encodedString) {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString , 0,
            decodedString.length);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Now, I want to display the image from database to web. The  web that I developed is using PHP. When I display the image, the image will display like this:

[image]

Below is the PHP code that I use to display the image from database to php page

```
echo "<td align='center'><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row["photo_before"])."'/></td>";
```

Can I know what is the problem? How to solve it?

Comment: try to remove the `<td align='center'><img src='` and the `/></td>`

Comment: Does error reporting show anything? Look at the HTML source also, see what that shows for the image/img.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner theres no error

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia when I remove, it will display a very long string

Comment: Copy your base64 string to here:https://tsaikoga.github.io/it-tools/web/index.html#/image64-page and see the image can be show or not

Comment: @TsaiKoga string from the database right?

Comment: No, this string `data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row["photo_before"])`

Comment: @TsaiKoga still same, no image displayed

Comment: Plz post your `$row["photo_before"]`

Comment: @TsaiKoga I still dont understand, can give example

Comment: @Hawau yes, but this example need to not be displayed in your code too

Comment: @TsaiKoga then how?

Comment: @Hawau try to get the `$row["photo_before"]` that u don't care and post it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202769/discussion-between-hawau-and-tsaikoga).

Comment: @Hawau in your `$row["photo_before"]` already contains `data:image/jpeg;base64,` part. So, use it like `<img src='".base64_encode($row["photo_before"])."'/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$row["photo_before"]` directly.

```php
echo "<td align='center'>
      <img src='".$row["photo_before"]."'/> 
      </td>";
```

Comment: @Hawau, glad u made it, if it's helpful, plz accept the answer.